# Google Analytics V3 API doesn't execute request in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, request, analytics

I want to implement Google Analytics API v3 in ASP MVC project. Because I never did that, I made a sample console application in which I've learned how to use this API and this is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var certByteArray = Properties.Resources.key;
        var serviceAccountEmail = "IdOfMyAccount@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certByteArray, "pswd", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            });

        var profileId = "ga:MyID";
        var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToShortDateString();
        var endDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        var metrics = "ga:visits,ga:pageviews,ga:users,ga:sessionDuration,ga:bounceRate";

        DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = service.Data.Ga.Get(profileId, startDate, endDate, metrics);
        request.Dimensions = "ga:country";
        GaData data = request.Execute();

        foreach (var row in data.Rows)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var h in data.ColumnHeaders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(h.Name + "      " + row[i].ToString());
                // Here get the column name and its values
                i++;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

In this app everything works well and I get the data very quickly. Problem starts, when I'm trying to use this code in MVC application. In debugging mode everything works well untill I get to

```
GaData data = request.Execute();
```

When I hit F10 key to step forward it seems like app is working and  browser is waiting on finish the action, but it isn't happening. Application_Error method isn't invoked at all in this case. In both apps I've installed the same NuGet packages.

Anyone have a clue why it isn't working in ASP MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few tries it's started to work with ExecuteAsync method invoked on request. This is the actual code, but still I have no idea how to make it synchronously.

```
public async Task<GaData> GetAnalysisData()
    {
        var certByteArray = Properties.Resources.key;
        var serviceAccountEmail = "MyId@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certByteArray, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        });

        var profileId = "ga:********";
        var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToShortDateString();
        var endDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        var metrics = "ga:visits,ga:pageviews,ga:users,ga:sessionDuration,ga:bounceRate";

        DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = service.Data.Ga.Get(profileId, startDate, endDate, metrics);
        request.Dimensions = "ga:country";
        var data = await request.ExecuteAsync();

        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Did you happen to find out the underlying issue? Even ExecuteAsync hangs forever for me,,, :(